# 2 ng-controller and need to share data between it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have 2 controller in my app.js

```
app = angular.module('dbaccess',[]);
app.controller('process', function($http, $scope,$location, $service){
    $scope.update = function(user){
            $scope.master = {};
            $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/dbaccess/saveData", $scope.master).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.resp = data;
                alert("This is the data" +data.message);
                $('.form-horizontal').hide();
                $('#response-message').html().text("Hello");                    
            })
            .error(function(data){
                alert("Error " +data.message);              
            })
        }
    });
    app.controller('usrEmailAddress', function($http,$scope,$location, $service){
        $scope.email = {};          
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/dbaccess/userlist").success(function(data){
            $scope.emails = data;
        }); 
    })
```

process controller is use to submit data to a java controller for processing and other usrEmailAddress controller is use to grab the json data from the java controller.

I have  index.jsp which is has ng-model. I would like email to pass to the process controller, but isn't able to do that. Any help will be great.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;
       charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
         <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="en" ng-app="dbaccess">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>This is the title of the page</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dbaccess/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">               

            <!-- 
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
            <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/example.js"></script>
            -->

            <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
         <body>
            <div class="container" ng-controller="emailAddress as address" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="requestedBy" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Requested By</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestedBy" placeholder="Requestor Name" ng-model="user.requestedBy"  required/>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div >
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">          Email Address</label>
                             <div class="col-sm-3 " ng-controller = 'usrEmailAddress'>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
                                    <option value=""> --Select Email Address -- </option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="mails in emails" value={{mails.email}} >{{mails.email}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="approval" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Approved By</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="approval" placeholder="XYZ" ng-model="user.approvedBy" readonly/>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="jiraTicket" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Jira Ticket</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jiraTicker" ng-model="user.jira"/>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reason" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Business Justification</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <textarea row="3" class="form-control"  required ng-model="user.requestJustification"></textarea>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="emergency"  class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Emergency </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="user.emergency">
                                <option value="yes" >YES</option>
                                <option value="no"> NO </option>
                            </select>
                          </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3" >
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update(user,user.approvedBy='XYZ')" >Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                    <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
                     <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
            </div>  
        </body>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

            <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/angular.js"></script>
             <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/example.js"></script>
            <script src="/dbaccess/resources/js/validator.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is what services were designed for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an angular `service` or `factory`.

For example:

```
app.factory('emailService', function($q, $http) {
  var emails;

  var getEmails = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (emails) { 
      deferred.resolve(emails);
    } else {
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/dbaccess/userlist")
        .then(function(data){
          emails = data;
          deferred.resolve(emails);
        }); 
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return {
    getEmails: getEmails
  }
});
```

Here, I've used `$q` so that you always return a promise, whether you make the `$http` call or not.  You either return the list of emails that's already stored in memory, or you go get the emails, store them in memory, and use that.

Your controllers will simply inject the `emailService` and call `getEmails`

```
app.controller('usrEmailAddress', function($scope, emailService){
  emailService.getEmails().then(function(emails) {
    $scope.emails = emails;
  });
});

app.controller('process', function($http, $scope,$location, $service, emailService){
  // [...]

  emailService.getEmails().then(function(emails) {
    $scope.emails = emails;
  });
});
```

Whichever service hits `getEmails` first will populate the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is where *AngularJS Services* comes to play.

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

Learn more about services in the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

AngularJS Services are singeltons, a single instance, and are only instantiated when an application component depends on it.

Answer (score -1):

you can look $emit and $broadcast  in [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)